# Clickjack protection block VF Page in Lightning Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, developer-edition

I created VF page and a lightning component, then embed VF Page to lightning component. Like follow code:

```
<iframe src="/apex/MyTestPage" width="100%" frameBorder="0" />
```

In Session Settings my settings as follow image
[image]

I set Whitelisted Domains as follow
[image]

When I use this lightning component in Lightning App Builder I got a gray screen and show refused to connect error.

May I ask help for how to resolved this issue.

Best wishes,
Lee

Comment: It could be because of the Clickjack protection so can you please try by turning off the settings which you have shown in the screenshot provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Shirisha Pathuri said it correct: It could be because of the Clickjack protection so can you please try by turning off the settings which you have shown in the screenshot provided.

So just turn off these settings.